# How to implement a search like the google maps address search?

Tags: android

I would like to create a search in my app which acts like the map search in the Google Maps app.
I have creates an an auto complete text view which updates dynamically based on the results of the `Geocoder.GetLocationByName()` Method.
However the results retrieved from this function are really bad and not at all consistent with the text I pass to it.
Is there a better method of doing this to achieve accurate results?

Answer (score 0):

So it's not the geosearch that's your problem, but the autocompletion, right? Well I assume you need the whole set of possible values in order to obtain a decent auto-completion. Another way would be to take apart the google javascript code that performs the auto-completion and talk to their servers, pretending you're typing into one of "their" fields. However, this isn't only probably against their terms of service but also a bit shaky because they might a) detect and prevent this or b) change their interface in the future.

Your best guess would be to get a list of all cities, streets, etc in question.

Comment: Thats a nice idea thogh I am sure as you said it probably is a breach of the terms.
However Im not using the Web API i am using the android class GeoCoder.

Comment: well I don't see how that would keep you from abusing another of their services ;)

Comment: hehe lol, it doesn't i guess. But I'm pretty sure there is a "proper" way of getting this achieved.

Answer (score 0):

**hopefully this should be able to do the trick :=)**

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete

good luck (testing it myself right now)